# I cannot load random forest model using joblib. I am getting a scipy error

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I have a random forest model that I am building in a pipeline that uses **scikit-learn v0.23.1**. Once the model is built I am downloading it and trying to locally load it using `model = joblib.load("model_name.joblib")`.

However, when I try to do this I get the error:

```
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/joblib/numpy_pickle.py", line 587, in load
    obj = _unpickle(fobj, filename, mmap_mode)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/joblib/numpy_pickle.py", line 506, in _unpickle
    obj = unpickler.load()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.7/3.7.9_3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/pickle.py", line 1088, in load
    dispatch[key[0]](self)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.7/3.7.9_3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/pickle.py", line 1385, in load_stack_global
    self.append(self.find_class(module, name))
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.7/3.7.9_3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/pickle.py", line 1426, in find_class
    __import__(module, level=0)
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'scipy.sparse._csr'
```

I have done this process fine for a while and only recently it has started to get the above error.

Comment: does `pip list` shows the package `scipy`? if yes, i would try re-installing `scipy`. `pip uninstall scipy
pip install scipy`

Comment: So I managed to solve it. The pipeline was building the model using python 3.8 and I was loading it locally using python 3.7. Not sure why that stopped working recently but switching locally to 3.8 meant that it worked.